# Linq does not update related item on add new

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm, windows-phone

I'm building a Windows Phone app that has to do with card decks and played games. I have based it all on this example [How to create a local database app with MVVM for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286405(v=vs.105).aspx). As would be pretty obvious one Deck can have several played Games. Therefore I have built it as such that Deck is the "Category" and the Game is the "Todo" from the example. The specific code of the Model and ViewModel is attached.

When I add a new Game it gets a Deck which it belongs to. This works fine.

The problem is that the DeckGame collection in the Deck table (apparently) does not get noticed that it has recieved a new member and thus when returning to the page with all the deck information the new Game is not present.

In plain words, the Game knows which deck it belongs to but the deck does not know it has new Games.

When I restart the app all the new games are present.

This is the part of my code which I belive is relevant.

This is the add new game Method (ViewModel) which is called when a new Game is registerd.

```
    public void AddGame(GameItem newGameItem)
    {
        // Add a to-do item to the data context.
        _Db.Games.InsertOnSubmit(newGameItem);

        // Save changes to the database.
        _Db.SubmitChanges();

        // Add a to-do item to the "all" observable collection.
        Games.Add(newGameItem);
    }
```

This is the Game part of the Deck-Game relationship

```
// Internal column for the associated Deck ID value
    [Column]
    internal int _gameDeckId;

    // Entity reference, to identify the Deck "storage" table
    private EntityRef<DeckItem> _gameDeck;

    // Association, to describe the relationship between this key and that "storage" table
    [Association(Storage = "_gameDeck", ThisKey = "_gameDeckId", OtherKey = "DeckId", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public DeckItem GameDeck
    {
        get { return _gameDeck.Entity; }
        set
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("GameDeck");
            _gameDeck.Entity = value;

            if (value != null)
            {
                _gameDeckId = value.DeckId;
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanging("GameDeck");
        }
    }
```

And this is the Deck part of the relationship

```
// Define the entity set for the collection side of the relationship.
    private EntitySet<GameItem> _deckGames;

    [Association(Storage = "_deckGames", OtherKey = "_gameDeckId", ThisKey = "DeckId")]
    public EntitySet<GameItem> DeckGames
    {
        get { return this._deckGames; }
        set { this._deckGames.Assign(value); }
    }


    // Assign handlers for the add and remove operations, respectively.
    public DeckItem()
    {
        _deckGames = new EntitySet<GameItem>(
            new Action<GameItem>(this.attach_Game), 
            new Action<GameItem>(this.detach_Game)
            );
    }

    // Called during an add operation
    private void attach_Game(GameItem game)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanging("GameItem");
        game.GameDeck = this;
    }

    // Called during a remove operation
    private void detach_Game(GameItem game)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanging("GameItem");
        game.GameDeck = null;
    }
```

Any help appreciated, don't hesitate to ask for more details or code!

*Edited 2015-01-01*

```
    // All Game items.
    private ObservableCollection<GameItem> _games;
    public ObservableCollection<GameItem> Games
    {
        get { return _games; }
        set
        {
            _games = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Games");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is "Games" an `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: As McGarnagle mentioned, "Games" must be an ObservalbeCollection.

Comment: Yes it is. I have edited the question to include this information.

Comment: I did solve the problem with a temporary solution. I created a new instance of the ViewModel at every page. This gives the desired  result but I would still like it to be one central ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose there is an error in your code (and, sad but true, in the MSDN sample).

Just look at this snippet:

```
public DeckItem GameDeck
{
    get { return _gameDeck.Entity; }
    set
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanging("GameDeck");
        _gameDeck.Entity = value;

        if (value != null)
        {
            _gameDeckId = value.DeckId;
        }

        NotifyPropertyChanging("GameDeck");
    }
}
```

You notify twice that the `GameDeck` property **is about to change**, but never that it **has been changed**.

The second `NotifyPropertyChanging` method call should be replaced with a `NotifyPropertyChanged` method call.

Comment: It caught my eye as well an I did try this but to no use. But I was rather messing around at that point so it might work. I will try again.

Comment: It turned out to be problems elsewhere. Even though this was not _the_ problem in this case you are still correct and I have therefore marked your answer as correct.